# Does calling the same jQuery UI slider twice create a different slider object each time?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am wondering if calling the same slider object twice (or more) creates two different objects?  Do I need to first destroy the original before calling the other?  How do I check if two slider objects exists using Firebug/Chrome console?

html:

```
<div id='test-slider'></div>
```

javascript:

```
$('#test-slider').slider({
  value: test_value,
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
  step: 1
});

$('#test-slider').slider({
  value: test_value_2,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 10
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it sets the first slider object to the value of whatever you use in the second time you call it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Is there a way to check in Firebug/Chrome Console on the number of objects that exist in the browser?